# USB 3.1 port wiring for charging

Tags: power-supply, usb, battery-charging, charger, pins

I'm building an USB charger with a linear PSU just for hobby and I want to install an USB 3.1 port so it can supply 900 mA max.

If I only connect up the USB 3.1 port VBUS and GND pins, will the device recognize it as USB 2.0?

I'd like to know what I should do with the other five wires, as if I were charging from a computer USB 3.1 port but without the data transfer.

Comment: um, linear regulation at 900 mA – that sounds like nearly universally a pretty bad idea. From which voltage are you going down to 5V?

Comment: Marcus, from 8V.

Comment: Then you'd be converting > 2.7W to heat. Your linear regulator: Does it specify how much hotter it gets for 1 W of load (usually it's in the datasheet as "thermal resistance")? For example, [this](https://www.digikey.de/en/products/detail/onsemi/MC7805CDTRKG/921037) rather classical 7805-derivative in a power-optimized packages gets 92°C hotter for every 1W of loss without a heatsink; so, if we start at room temperature, at a little more than 1W, the maximum temperature of 125°C will quickly be reached, unless you invest in a large heatsink.

Comment: It says 50ºC, I can use some transistor to share the current, got some heatsink and fan here too, if my project goes wrong the charger will use USB 2.0 anyway, but I wanna try USB 3.1 first and for this I would like to know the wiring diagram.

Comment: the wiring diagram doesn't exist without knowledge of your actual regulator. And no, you cannot use a resistor to share the current. And adding a fan and a heatsink just to use a linear regulator is a pretty expensive and complicating approach – this is pretty much switch-mode power supply's standard use case.

Comment: Marcus, i said transistor, not resistor, like the datasheet shows, and I know that SMPS will do the job easily, but I still want to build it.

Comment: sorry, I mistyped! Doesn't make much sense. The same heat is generated and needs to get rid of. So, wrong approach.

Comment: Thanks for the help Marcus, but my doubt remains unanswered.

Comment: yes, and you've not addressed what your specific regulator is, so I'm afraid nobody will be able to help you with your endeavour.